# Using IF ELSE Statement around SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

This is my program where I need to verify if the username or password already exists but if I add another using statement for the verification it still goes through the database. How should I use IF ELSE statement having an sql statement inside e.g ("@username" == _f3txtuser.text)

```
    private void _F3Register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (_F3txtUser.Text == "" || _F3txtPass.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("Please Fill The Missing Informations");
        else if (_F3txtPass.Text != _F3txtCheckPass.Text)
            MessageBox.Show("Password Do Not Match");

        else if (("@USERNAME" == _F3txtUser) || ("@PASSWORD" == _F3txtPass))
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password already Exists");

        else
        {
            using (SqlConnection _sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)) //Database Connection
            {
                _sqlcon.Open();


                String query2 = "Insert into LOGINFORM(USERNAME, PASSWORD, FNAME, LNAME, AGE) values(@USERNAME, @PASSWORD, @FNAME, @LNAME, @AGE)"; // Database Command for Insertion

                using (SqlCommand _sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query2, _sqlcon)) //using database connection and command in one method
                {
                    _sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", _F3txtUser.Text.Trim());
                    _sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", _F3txtPass.Text.Trim());
                    _sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", _txtFN.Text.Trim());
                    _sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", _txtLN.Text.Trim());
                    _sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AGE", _txtAge.Text.Trim());
                    _sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Registration Successfull");
                Clear();

            }
        }
    }
    void Clear()
    {
        _F3txtUser.Clear();
        _F3txtPass.Clear();
        _txtFN.Clear();
        _txtLN.Clear();
        _txtAge.Clear();
        _F3txtCheckPass.Clear();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: code should be here as text

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 1):

You can have a method like below:

```
    private bool UserNameOrPasswordExists(string userName, string password)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var query = "Select * from LOGINFORM where USERNAME='@USERNAME' or PASSWORD='@PASSWORD'";
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", userName);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASSWORD", password);
                var result = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return result > 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then replace the third if else with this:

```
    else if (UserNameOrPasswordExists(_F3txtUser, _F3txtPass))
        MessageBox.Show("Username or Password already Exists");
```

Comment: Sir may i ask what do you mean by "Your connection string"

Comment: "Your connection string" means the connection string variable that you have used: "connectionstring"